# How to share Google Site with entire domain using Apps Script SitesApp?

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sites

Using SitesApp.AddEditor() you can add users to a specific Google Site.
But how can you add the entire domain?
The Google Sites API allows this, just cannot figure out if that method was implemented in Apps Script.

It would appear not, just want to confirm.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Just create a group that contains all users in the domain, then add that group as an editor.

Answer (score 0):

Google Apps Script Sites service does not (yet) have a method to set/change the visibility of sites. However, there are possible work-arounds for this:

**[By default, all users in a domain can find and edit newly created sites](https://support.google.com/a/answer/1751957?hl=en)**. You do not have to add individual users as editors in this case. Google Apps administrator for your domain may have changed the default visibility setting to *private*, though. In this case you/site owner will have to change this setting on per-site basis by adding users as viewers/editors to the site (read on below). Check with your Google Apps administrator about default visibility setting for sites under your domain. [See this help page for more details](https://support.google.com/a/answer/1751957?hl=en).

If your domain's default sites visibility is set to *private*, and your administrators do not want to change that, you still have another option: **you can share a site with a group** instead of individual users. Any users added to the group later will inherit group's access to the site (or their individual level access, whichever is higher; i.e. if a group has "view" access, but individual user in the group has "edit" access, they will be an editor). **[Google Apps administrators can create domain-wide groups which include all users in a domain](https://support.google.com/a/answer/66338?hl=en)**. If your domain has such a group, just add the group as editor to the site using [`.addEditor('groupemail@yourdomain.com')`](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/sites/site#addEditor(String)) method to allow all users in your domain to edit the site. Otherwise ask your Google Apps administrator if they can create such a group.